# How to hide fields for specific record in django-admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to hide field for specific record in djano-admin?
For example if I have a model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(..., null=True)
    author = models.CharField(...)
```

I want to hide an author in admin panel for record with pk = 1. I found the solution as

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("pk", "get_title_or_nothing")

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj.pk == "1":
            self.exclude = ("author", )
        form = super(BookAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form
```

It works well untill I am coming back from record with pk == 1 to other records, in this case all records in table have hided author field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because once the `"author"` field gets appended to `self.exclude`, it just stays there.

**For Django >= 1.11:**

A better place to exclude fields *dynamically* is in [`ModelAdmin.get_exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_exclude). It was introduced in Django 1.11.

```
def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj and obj.pk == 1:
        # don't modify self.exclude
        # instead return it with the extra added field
        return self.exclude + ('author',)
    return self.exclude
```

---

**For Django < 1.11:**

For older versions, you can do something like this:

```
class BookAdmin(...):
    exclude = (# common excluded fields)
    original_exclude = exclude

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj and obj.pk == 1:
        self.exclude += ('author',)
    else:
        # change it back to the original_exclude
        # for other objects
        self.exclude = self.original_exclude
    form = super(BookAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    return form
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'tuple' "

Comment: @Popka Set `exclude = ()` in your `ModelAdmin` class and try again.

Comment: @xyres, What if I want it to be on a particular user like non superuser

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris You can check for `request.user.is_superuser`. This will be false for non superusers.